# Antd popover not triggering even though code is the same as example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have been loving using the ant design library for this project, but for some reason, I can't get the popovers to work. [Here](https://www.loom.com/share/26f7254d47cb4ca298122eedb7691c2b) is a video of what I'm getting.

Here is the code

```
<Popover
  content={
    <div>
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
  }
  title="Title"
>
  <Button type="primary">Hover me</Button>
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your video, it doesn't look like you have set up `antd` properly because the button styling looks very odd.

You are probably missing the CSS import that allows `antd` components to work correctly check out this documentation: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

You need to add this line in your index.js or App.js: `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`